# How can I reduce recursion in Couchbase?

Tags: performance, recursive, couchbase

Sometimes, you need to access a certain document `(A)`, but you do not know the key for that document (A), as that data is stored in a different document `(B)`. So now, if you want to fetch `A`, it looks like the following:

```
fetch B
parse B
get name of A
fetch A
```

Now, obviously, this doesn't look too bad, but after three or four levels of recursion, especially once you have larger documents (100 KB+), this can become a performance issue:

```
fetch A (10K)
parse A
fetch B (100K)
parse B
still parsing B
fetch C (1M)
waiting for C
parse C
still parsing C
and still parsing C
fetch D (1K)
```

How can I reduce the amout of recursion required in a scenario like this? I mean, obviously, I could rewrite the documents, but if that is not an option, what exactly can I do?

My documents are all JSON documents; does Couchbase have some sort of feature to fetch documents recursively for me?

Comment: No offence to couchbase but if it can't do - efficiently - a simple 4-table join, you should consider using a boring old SQL product.